# why my Local Storage show me "object HTMLSpanElement"?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hello everybody I am relatively new to coding. I have a local storage project in object oriented javascript for reservation data and to display them in a reservation summary.I am currently blocked, I manage to recover the various values ​​with "getItem", but when I want to display them on my html it displays "object HTMLSpanElement".

the only solution I found is to add ".textcontent" at the end of my variables but it doesn't work.

**this is my code**

```
class information{
constructor(){
        this.StationName = document.getElementById("StationName");
        this.name = document.getElementById("name");
        this.firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
        this.adresse = document.getElementById("adresse");
        this.PlacesTotal = document.getElementById("PlacesTotal");
        this.nbrVeloDispo = document.getElementById("nbrVeloDispo"); 
    };

initstorage(){
    var StationName = document.getElementById("StationName").textContent;
    var name =  document.getElementById("name").value; 
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value 
    var adresse = document.getElementById("adresse").textContent; 
    var PlacesTotal = document.getElementById("PlacesTotal").textContent;
    var nbrVeloDispo = document.getElementById("nbrVeloDispo").textContent; 
    };   

initreservation(){
    var StationName = localStorage.getItem("StationName");
    var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    var firstname = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
    var adresse = localStorage.getItem("adresse");
    var PlacesTotal = localStorage.getItem("PlacesTotal");
    var nbrVeloDispo = localStorage.getItem("nbrVeloDispo");                    
    };       

reserver(){
    document.getElementById("signature").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("panneaureservation").style.display = "none";
};
}; 

document.getElementById("reservation1").innerHTML = StationName;

const stockage = new information();
document.getElementById("reserve").onclick = function() { stockage.initstorage(); stockage.initreservation(); stockage.reserver(); }
```

Thank you for taking your time to help me.

Comment: have you tried `innerText` instead of `textContent`?

Comment: @Bargros That shouldn't affect this.

Comment: How are you using `setItem`?

Comment: The problem is in the code that saves to local storage. It's saving the DOM element, not its content.

Comment: @Christian You can't. The reference is converted to a string, which is why it stores `[object HTMLSpanElement]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `localStorage.setItem()` you are attempting to store **a reference** to the DOM element itself instead of the **content** of that element.  Since `localStorage` only stores `string`s, the object implicitly gets its `.toString()` method called on it and a string representation of the object's type and element name is what gets stored.

Here's an example of what's happening (described above):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("div").toString());
```

```html
<div>My div element</div>
```

Once that happens, you can't extract the reference later because all you have is the string name of the object.

You didn't show that code, but that's what needs to be updated. It should store the string value that you will want to get later. Something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("StationName", document.getElementById("StationName").textContent);
localStorage.setItem("name", document.getElementById("name").value);
localStorage.setItem("firstname", document.getElementById("firstname").value);
localStorage.setItem("adresse", document.getElementById("adresse").textContent);
localStorage.setItem("PlacesTotal", document.getElementById("PlacesTotal").textContent);
localStorage.setItem("nbrVeloDispo", document.getElementById("nbrVeloDispo").textContent);
```

Where you set the `.textContent` of non-form field DOM elements and the `.value` of form field DOM elements. And, of course, you don't want this code to run against form field data until the form has been completed.